# Closed form of an averaging series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the expression
$$
f(\mathbf{x},n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{e^{-k^2\overline{x_k}}-e^{-(k+1)^2\overline{x_k}}}{(2k+1)\overline{x_k}}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}=[x_{-n},\cdots,x_{-2},x_{-1},x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n}]^T$ and
$$
\overline{x_k}=\frac{1}{2k+1}\sum_{|i|\leq k} x_i
$$
with $0<x_i<\infty$, for all $i\in\{-n,...,-1,0,1,...,n\}$.

What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\mathbf{x},n)$? If not a closed formula, is it possible to find an upper bound?

**My attempt:** Following @metamorphy's answer [presented here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629728/closed-form-or-upper-bound-for-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-0n-frace-k2x-e), for the case where $x_i\equiv x,\forall i$, and given that $\{x_i\}$ is bounded, one would hope there exists $k^*$ such that
$$
f(\mathbf{x},\infty)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{-k^2\overline{x_k}}-e^{-(k+1)^2\overline{x_k}}}{(2k+1)\overline{x_k}}\simeq \frac{1}{\overline{x_{k^*}}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{-k^2\overline{x_{k^*}}}-e^{-(k+1)^2\overline{x_{k^*}}}}{2k+1}
$$
which, following the answer to the linked question, leads to the local approximation
$$
f(\mathbf{x},\infty)\simeq \frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\overline{x_{k^*}}}}
$$
However, in simulations, this does not seem to work for numerical attempts on various values of $k^*$. Nonetheless, I expect an approximation like this to be possible.

Just to better visualize the problem, here is the plot of $f(\mathbf{x},n)$, where the "data" vector $\mathbf{x}$ was generated via a random walk with very small increments ($10^{-5}$) and $x_i\in(0,0.1)$

[image]

The goal is to approximate the blue curve. Any ideas?

**Comment on $\mathbf{x}$:** The randomness of $\mathbf{x}$ might difficult finding a potential solution and make this problem way too broad. Therefore, we may take it to behave "continuously" enough. For example, it can be taken to be a fine discretisation of a continuous function, as sketched here

[image]

Naturally the answer should be $\mathbf{x}$-dependent, but I wonder if it is possible to still make an assertion on an approximation to $f$, given, for example, a local mean approximation, as seen, for some $k^*$,

[image]

Where $\overline{x_n}$ is the overall mean. Note that, for each $k$, the mean changes little, and we may also assume
$$
|\overline{x_k}-\overline{x_{k-1}}|<\epsilon
$$
for some small $\epsilon$.