# Approximation of $\frac1x\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{e^{-k^2x}-e^{-(k+1)^2x}}{2k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

Consider the following function
$$
f(x,n)=\frac1x\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{e^{-k^2x}-e^{-(k+1)^2x}}{2k+1}
$$
For small $x$, is there a way of approximating $f(x,n)$ by something like an inverse power law on $x$, depending on $n$. I am looking for something in the form $f(x,n)\simeq \alpha(n) x^{\beta(n)}$. If not, is there any function that approximates $f$, simplifying the expression on the RHS?

**Note:** For multiple various of $n$, for example, here are the plots of the family of functions defined by $f(x,n)$

[image]

Also, the limit $n\to\infty$ was studied for a similar function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629728/closed-form-or-upper-bound-for-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-0n-frace-k2x-e) ($xf(x,n)$).

**My attempt:** We can rewrite the summand as
$$
\frac{e^{-k^2x}(1-e^{-(2k+1)x})}{2k+1}
$$
Now, we can use the Taylor expansion of the exponential function $e^x \approx 1 + x$ for small $x$. We then get
$$
1-e^{-(2k+1)x}\approx (2k+1)x.
$$
Thus, for small $x$, the summand becomes
$$
\frac{e^{-k^2x}(2k+1)x}{2k+1}\approx e^{-k^2x}x
$$
Using this approximation, we can rewrite the original function as
$$
f(x,n)\approx \frac1x \sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k^2x}x=\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k^2x}
$$
This expression is simpler than the original one, although it's not in the form of an inverse power law. Any ideas on how to work it further?

Answer (score 2):

The approximation of the content of the sum divided by $x$ provides
$$
\frac1x\frac{e^{-k^2x}-e^{-(k+1)^2x}}{2k+1}\approx 1-\frac{1}{2}(2k^2+2k+1)x
$$
Then, summing up from $0$ to $n$ gives
$$
(n+1)-\frac{1}{6} \left(2 n^3+6 n^2+7 n+3\right) x
$$

Answer (score 2):

The second sum you provided, i.e. $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \exp(-k^2x)$, is possible to take a step further using Euler Maclaurin summation. This gives

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)  \sim \int_0^n f(z)dz + \frac{1}{2}f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f(n) + \frac{B_1}{2!} \left(f^{(1)}(n) - f^{(1)}(0) \right)
$$

with $f(z) = \exp(-z^2x)$ this gives that

$$
\int_0^n \exp(-z^2x)dz = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \text{erf} (\sqrt{x}n)} {2\sqrt{x}}
$$

and so one arrives at the approximation

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \exp(-k^2 x)  \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \text{erf} (\sqrt{x}n)} {2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\exp(-n^2x) - \frac{1}{6}nx\exp(-n^2x)
$$

E.g. setting $x=0.1$ gives that the largest relative error is around $8\cdot 10^{-5}$ and occurs for $n=1$.

This works decently for rather small $x$ for the original sum as well but even for $x=0.01$ or so the (largest) absolute error is around $6\%$ (the approximation has the same shape as the sum evaluated numerically but converges towards a somewhat lower value when $n$ increases).  It would be necessary to include additional terms in the Taylor expansion and proceed likewise to account for this.