# Is $\sqrt{\pi}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k^2}-e^{-(k+1)^2}}{2k+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pi

Is it true that
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k^2}-e^{-(k+1)^2}}{2k+1}
$$
**Context:** Attempting to find an easier proof for [this estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636332/487230), when $x=1$.

**My attempt:** [Leibniz's Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_Formula_for_Pi) gives
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
$$
which is relatively closer to my expression. However, I am not sure how to rewrite this with the square root, if possible at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Could this have something to do with the normal distribution?

Comment: Numerical evidence says "no".

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I like that. How?

Comment: Taylor expand $\sqrt(x)$ about a point of a=1 and then take $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and then equate that to the sum you are trying to show the equality to, and see that if their difference is 0 then it must be true.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives a value of $0.752298$ which isn't $\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%28%28e%5E%28-k%5E2%29-e%5E-%28%28k%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%2F%282k%2B1%29

Comment: Just compute the first few terms in your preferred programming language.It turns out $\sum - \sqrt{\pi/4}\approx-0.134$. The series converges quickly ans is easy computationally, so no reason for a computation to be so far off of $0$.

Comment: I wonder if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k^2}}{2k+1}$ is related to a theta function?

Comment: This is the same as $\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-k^2}}{2 k+1}$